# Header for ListView with passing string

Tags: android, listview, header

I want to pass a string from my java class to xml. And this string will be a header for listview. How I can do that?

Comment: Please explain in detail about your working

Comment: I have a listview inside of listview. And I want that when user in second list view, there will be header of this chosen category. for ex. in first activity there is strings array: foods, colors ... Then when user click on colors, will open new listview and in this activity there will be blue, red... And here is what I need, How I can put this colors string in second activity like header. I hope I could explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/SportsLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >


   <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/headingtext"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="top"
         ></TextView>

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/eventslist1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >

    </ListView>




</LinearLayout>
```

In first activity you write

```
`
 Intent i=new Intent(PresentActivity.this,NextActivity.class); 
i.putExtra("keyname","String which is to be used as heading for listview");
startActivity(i);`
```

In second activity

```
 String heading= getIntent().getStringExtra("keyname");
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.headingtext);
txt.setText(heading);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one text view above the list view in your xml layout.
Now when you call the activity containing list view send the string using intent object as below
        Intent i=new Intent(PresentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("keyname","String which is to be used as heading for listview");

then start your activity using
          startActivity(i);
In your second activity you write the following lines

```
    String heading= getIntent().getStringExtra("keyname");
    TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txthead);
    txt.setText(heading);
```

Comment: you understand me wrong, I don't want to take text from xml, I want to pass text from java to xlm

Comment: That is what i told you declare text view in xml and remove that android:text line when yo send a string from one activity to another using putExtra and set that text using setText method using java

Comment: Can you get it or do you need any example

Comment: I did exactly what u write, and I know about this putExtra but still in my xml there is not seems this text which I have in java. If u can give some simple example, it will be great!